# Estimating a nonmonotonic heteroscedastic relationship between two variables with imbalanced data: Haggling on Neopets

Tags: heteroscedasticity, smoothing, games

Like many people these days, I'm afflicted with the disease of recapitulating my work in my leisure. So it is that I find myself wanting to use data analysis to reverse-engineer the haggling mechanic in the venerable online game Neopets. As a first step, I'm trying to learn how the shopkeeper comes up with a counteroffer to the player's first offer. How this works from the player's perspective is:

- The shopkeeper advertises an item at a specific price. I call this the sticker price.
- The player initiates haggling by making an offer (which presumably will be equal to or less than the sticker price).
- The shopkeeper either makes a counteroffer (which will always be greater than the player's offer, and almost always lower than the sticker price) or accepts the player's price.

All three of these prices must be positive integers. (They are in the in-game currency called Neopoints, or NP.)

I've collected a whole lot of data ([over 9,000](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SiMHTK15Pik) observations), by automatically making offers and recording the counteroffers. You can get it at:

http://arfer.net/downloads/neopets_haggling_firstround.csv.gz

Two important things I've learned so far are:

1. No shopkeeper will accept or offer something below 3/4 of the sticker price (well, maybe one or two NP below). (This is something Neopets players have already known for a while; [e.g.](http://www.neopets.com/~Fonsuvie))
2. The distribution of counteroffers, expressed as a fraction of the sticker price, is determined by the ratio of your offer to the sticker price. That is, if `p1` is the sticker price, `offer` is your offer, and `p2` is the counteroffer, then the distribution of `p2/p1` is determined by `offer/p1`. In short, differences in sticker price can be ignored for the purposes of data analysis so long as we work with ratios.

Here's a plot of the data I have so far:

```
ggplot(data = with(d, data.frame(x = offer / p1, y = p2 / p1)), aes(x, y)) +
    geom_point(alpha = .2) +
    geom_smooth(method = "loess",
        color = "blue", linetype = "dotted") +
    stat_summary_bin(fun.y = mean, binwidth = .02,
        geom = "line",
        color = "red") +
    coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, .75), ylim = c(.74, 1), expand = F) +
    xlab("offer / p1") + ylab("p2 / p1")
```

[image: Plot of counteroffers]

Each point is a counteroffer. Clearly, the relationship is nonmonotonic and heteroscedastic.

The dotted blue curve is a LOESS fit. The solid red curve connects the means of `p2 / p1` in each bin of `offer / p1`, where the bins are .02 units wide.

(You'll note that the amount of data I have varies quite a bit between values of `offer / p1`, which is because I've used various different strategies of computing offers over the course of data collection.)

It seems to me that LOESS isn't doing a good job here. In particular, we have a great deal of data at `offer / p1 == .25`, meaning we should have quite a good estimate of the mean, but the curve doesn't go through the mean there (where the binned-means curve is). I've played around with the parameters of R's `loess`, cubic-spline regression (`splines::ns`), and generalized additive models (`mgcv::gam`), but I haven't gotten anything better. And obviously, the binned-means approach is too coarse and makes a curve that's too wiggly. Any hints?

Here's a plot of the univariate density at each of several offer ratios. The vertical lines indicate means.

[image: Faceted plot of counteroffers]

Comment: Have you looked at the conditional distributions (e.g. data in a single "x" bin)? In particular, how sure are you that the mean is an appropriate "summary"? My default would probably be to do a bin-quartile plot (median +/- "error bars"). I guess the concentrated "streaks" are due to your heuristic for making automated offers?

Comment: Respectively: [yes](https://i.imgur.com/hiDm2Z2.png); pretty sure; yes, that's what I'm talking about above at "You'll note that the amount of data I have…".

Comment: Thanks for the extra info! (Tou might put the conditional PDF pic in the question?) The conditionals look pretty unimodal (+/- your KDE bandwidth). Note that the x=0.25 one, where you noted the LOESS/bin-avg gap, is perhaps pos.-skewed, and the bin-avg looks closer to the mode. This "skew" looks like perhaps an artifact, due to  clamping to max(y,0.75)? Regardless, the LOESS result may suggest the x=0.25 PDF is an "outlier", meaning the nearby p(y|x) PDFs differ, so the x-smoothing is bringing the mean up? Have you checked a 2D KDE? (perhaps in log-log space?)

Comment: @GeoMatt22 "This 'skew' looks like perhaps an artifact, due to clamping to max(y,0.75)?" — Yeah, that's what I suspect: censoring at .75. I've never done KDE in 2D before. Can you point me to any references for that?

Comment: There is probably an R package for 2D KDE? (I do not use R, but [this](https://www.r-bloggers.com/5-ways-to-do-2d-histograms-in-r/) might be helpful.) In Matlab I typically do a quick approximation by 1) make a 2D histogram over a fine grid, then 2) smooth it by convolution with a 2D sampling of the kernel (e.g. a Gaussian-blur filter).

Comment: @GeoMatt22 On second thought, 2D KDE doesn't make sense because I'm not trying to estimate the distribution of `offer / p1`, since I chose those values myself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45165/discussion-between-geomatt22-and-kodiologist).

Comment: It looks to me  like the relationship may not be smooth; in particular, the changes in spread (and with them, likely the mean) seem to suggest different algorithms kicking in at particular points. e.g. see the change from $\leq 40\%$ to $>40\%$ near the bottom.

Comment: @Glen_b Well spotted. I'm collecting some more data from those odd areas now.

Comment: Those conditional densities are particularly interesting, They seem to bear out the idea of a different scheme operating (it looks like a mix of two different distributions (or perhaps more than two) that kicks in at least in the vicinity of 30-40% or maybe 25-40%; below that you seem to have a different relationship than operates above it, and in between you seem to have a mixture, with changing proportions as the predictor (percentage) changes from 30ish to 40